# Modifying existing AWS Config Delivery channel via CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm having issues updating/modifying AWS Config via CloudFormation. The use case is to begin streaming changes to an SNS Topic on an existing AWS Config delivery channel that currently only has an S3 bucket configured on it.

Code looks like the following:

```
        "ConfigDeliveryChannel": {
            "Type": "AWS::Config::DeliveryChannel",
            "Properties": {
                "S3BucketName": {"Ref": "ConfigBucket"},
                "SnsTopicARN": {
                    "Ref": "ConfigTopic"
                }
            }
        },
```

Pretty basic stuff. I've tried to leave off the bucket since I don't want to update that, but CloudFormation complained it was required. Ok, so I now have a parameter to take in the bucket name. The SNS topic is a resource created further down in my template. However when I execute my stack I get the following error:

```
Failed to put delivery channel '<name>' because the maximum number of delivery channels: 1 is reached. (Service: AmazonConfig; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MaxNumberOfDeliveryChannelsExceededException; )
```

So how can this be done? Is this an impossible task via CloudFormation and must be done by hand via the console? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you've already set up AWS Config via console, so you have to delete the default delivery channel.

Using the AWS CLI run:

```
aws configservice get-status
aws configservice delete-configuration-recorder --configuration-recorder-name default
aws configservice delete-delivery-channel --delivery-channel-name default
```

Comment: Correct, I was attempting to this via CloudFormation at the time and the solution was that you can only have 1 delivery channel active at a time it looks like.